# Meaning of the slang Boo

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang

The following paragraph is from the story of Billy, Sally, and Joe:

> Billy and Sally were inside a dark room.
>   - Billy yelled "Boo" and scared Sally.
>   Then, Joe came in.
>   - Hey, boo, come over and sit here with me.

In the first line, I understand that Billy was trying to scare Sally, but in the second line, what was Joe trying to say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That slang term for Boo is often used as a term for a Boyfriend or Girlfriend or even towards a friend in the right setting. Think of it as a pet name similar to how you would use hunny/honey or the currently popular Bae.

John: "Hey Dave!"
Dave: "Hey Boo!"

Whilst typically it is reserved for a more romantic relationship it can be said between friends in a partially mocking/endeering way the same way you may refer to a friend as "hun" or "honey".

[Urban Dictionary : Boo](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=boo)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so Joy was trying to say "Hey friends, come over and sit here" . Would it make sense If i say : I have many boos in college?

Comment: @CandiedMango Boo

Comment: @randal'thor Hey Boo!

Comment: @Starkeen I added an example and a bit of an explanation, typically you wouldn't pluralise the word "boo" as it's originally meant for the singular boyfriend/girlfriend one would have.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer feel free to Accept it, otherwise let me know how I can improve it and help your understanding :) @Starkeen

Comment: It originated as a misspelling of "beau"

Comment: @slebetman That's in the wiki link but I can include in the main body if you like :)

Comment: I am unconvinced by the folk etymology of the Urban Collection of Random Guesses.  How did this *boo* come about with the others -- an attempt to scare, a jeer, a synonym for marijuana, or a mistake (when doubled)?

Comment: @deadrat Apart from it's relation to Beau it's origin seems unclear.

Comment: @CandiedMango What relation to *beau*?

Comment: False, boo is a term we use to describe a person we're getting to know, seeing, or early dating, before it's an agreed upon relationship